# Repair APFS partition with damaged / zeroed-out header

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, partition, apfs

This incident occurred a few months ago, so you will have to forgive my poor memory. Please let me know if anything needs clarification.

I had a Dell Latitiude E6410 that I was using as a hackintosh (read: I installed macOS on non-Apple hardware). It was booting macOS 10.15.3 Catalina off of an APFS volume using a Legacy-based [Clover](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cloverefiboot/) installation. I wanted to switch to a UEFI-based boot solution.
Unfortunately, my laptop had trouble detecting ESPs that weren't identified explicitly as FAT32 volumes, even if they were, in all other respects, FAT32 volumes.
Rather than wipe my hard drive and reinstall macOS completely, as I should have done, I attempted to change the partition type of the ESP from "ESP" to "FAT32" using either fdisk or gdisk.
As I recall, this did not work, so I used fdisk to reformat the ESP as a FAT32 partition. For whatever reason, the command used to do so was taking a bit longer than usual - I believe this was because it was formatting the FAT32 partition outside of its specified 200MB bounds, thus overwriting the following APFS header - so I cancelled the command. For whatever reason, I afterwards rebooted my computer, and was greeted with a lovely "no bootable volume found" screen from the laptop's BIOS.

My data was gone, or so I suspected at first. Here's what `diskutil list` reports:

```
/dev/disk4 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *275.1 GB   disk4
   1:                        EFI NO NAME                 209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk5         274.9 GB   disk4s2

/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +ERROR      disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4s2
```

`diskutil apfs list`:

```
APFS Containers (2 found)
|
...
|
+-- Container ERROR -69808
    ======================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk5
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      ERROR -69620
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   ERROR -69620
    Capacity Not Allocated:       ERROR -69620
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk4s2 D6816D3B-582B-485D-8CC4-0079AF1EBEBD
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk4s2
    |   Size:                       274854445056 B (274.9 GB)
    |
    +-> No Volumes
```

`fsck_apfs`:

```
** Checking the container superblock.
** Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
** Checking the space manager.
error: (oid 0x7126) cib: found zeroed-out block
error: failed to read spaceman cib 0x7126
   Space manager is invalid.
** The volume /dev/disk4s2 could not be verified completely.
```

`inspect_apfs` from [Jivan Pal's apfs-tools](https://github.com/jivanpal/apfs-tools) (see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373718/how-to-recover-apparently-missing-directory-and-data-from-apfs-volume-found-ze)): [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/DY87Pg3k)

I'd like to recover the data that was on this APFS volume, retaining original filesystem structure if possible. Note that I was able to use [R-Studio](https://www.r-studio.com/) to see the original "Hackintosh HD - Data" partition and view some of my files. However, for the most part, the filesystem structure was not preserved, mixing in a tragic amount of caches and the likes with my valuable data. Also note that I believe my conundrum is rather similar to [this conundrum](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383337/repair-a-damaged-partition-after-a-partitiondisk-action-in-recovery-mode-maco).

Thank you.